# Converter ArrayList em Object[][]

Tags: java, java-ee

Como fazer a conversão de um ArrayList para um Object 2D.

Meu Código Atual:

```
ArrayList<String> a = null;
    a = new ArrayList<String>();                    
            a.add("ABC");
            a.add("DEF");
            a.add("1");
            a.add("1");

//Converter para Object 2D
int n = a.size();
System.out.println("Tamanho do Array: "+n);
Object[][] data = new Object[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    data[i] =    a.toArray();
```

Desse jeito eu consigo pegar o primeiro valor do ArrayList, porém ele se repete em todas as posições, acredito que o motivo é porque não estou solicitando outras posições do arraylist na linha `data[i] =    a.toArray();`, tentei alterar essa linha para `data[i] =    a.get(i);` mais nesse caso recebo o erro "**Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Object[]**"

Comment: O que deve ter na segunda dimensão?

Comment: @Maniero, no meu arraylist eu obtenho os dados de uma tabela do banco de dados com a seguinte estrutura (Unidade Metálica, Aço, Tempo de Forno, Uniformidade). Eu preciso que cada linha recebida seja armazenada em um object 2D, mais estou sem nenhuma ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Então falta muita informação aí, sem entender o problema completamente não tem como responder isso.

Comment: Ok, vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Esta pergunta tem cheiro disso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132

Comment: @VictorStafusa, você está correto, estou pensando em uma forma de apresentar melhor o meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> a = null;
a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("ABC");
a.add("DEF");
a.add("1");
a.add("1");        

//Converter para Object 2D
int n = (a.size() + 1) / 2;
System.out.println("Tamanho do Array: " + n);
Object[][] data = new Object[n][n];
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = a.get(temp);
        temp++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + data[i][j] + "");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```